# BIND - named.conf.local and define variables/functions?

Tags: dns, bind

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and BIND 9.16.1. In `named.conf.local` i'm using three zones

```
zone "lan" in {

        type slave;

        file "/var/cache/bind/db.lan";

        masters { 192.168.0.7 };

};

zone "local2" in {

        type slave;

        file "/var/cache/bind/db.local2";

        masters { 192.168.0.7 };

        masterfile-format text;

};

zone "p2p" in {

        type slave;

        file "/var/cache/bind/db.p2p";

        masters { 192.168.0.7 };

        masterfile-format text;

};
```

But when I would like to change location for file save or masters IP, I need to do it separately per zone. Of course I know that I can use `vim` and substitution, but still. Is there any way to do it using variable or function or something like that? For example Like:

```
masterDNS="192.168.0.7"

    zone "p2p" in {
    
            type slave;
    
            file "/var/cache/bind/db.p2p";
    
            masters { masterDNS; };
    
            masterfile-format text;
    
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
masters masters-ips { 192.168.0.7; };

zone "p2p" in {
            type slave; 
            file "/var/cache/bind/db.p2p";
            masters { masters-ips; };
            masterfile-format text;
    };
```

[See additional examples](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/masters.html)